# Is there any motherboard that supports Ryzen 3xxx out of the box?

Tags: processor, motherboard, compatibility

I am thinking on building a computer. I would like to use one of the new Ryzen CPUs, probably the Ryzen 3600. The problem came up when I had to pick the motherboard. Most motherboards support the new Ryzen 300 series but only with a BIOS update. I don't have access to a Ryzen 200 series CPU (2xxx) so, I can't flash a BIOS by switching the CPUs. Is there any new motherboard that supports the new Ryzen CPUs out of the box or an old one that already comes with an updated BIOS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the X570 boards do not need a BIOS update. They were released specifically for the Ryzen 2 generation and may only need a BIOS update for specific CPU models that released later. Hopefully somebody that has actually used one of these boards can confirm that in an answer.

Comment: @Romen I'm not sure if you get me. I want to use a Gen 3 Ryzen, not a Gen 2. I also can't update the BIOS to support a new CPU if that CPU doesn't work with the motherboard in the first place. Also, pairing an X570 board with a Ryzen 5 3600 would just be a waste of money but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I do get you. Currently the X570 is the only chipset that supports a Ryzen 3X00 CPU out of the box (which *is* a "Ryzen 2" CPU). After some time you may find older X470 or B450 boards with the latest BIOS on store shelves, but for now that will be hard to find. You could also wait for the B550 chipset, which will be used on lower cost boards and probably still suppot PCIe 4.0 when it is released.

Comment: Sorry, I did make a mistake in my previous comments: "Ryzen 2" should be "Zen 2". A Ryzen 2X00 CPU is still "Zen 1" while 3X00 is "Zen 2". It's easy to confuse their model numbers and generation numbers because they don't match, and also because "Ryzen" and "Zen" refer to different things (CPU model vs architecure).

Comment: Thanks, @Romen. I think I'll wait for the B550 chipset.